# Mediawiki on Google App Engine Links Missing Title Parameter

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mediawiki

After installing and testing a copy of mediawiki on localhost using dev_appserver.py I deployed the installation to Google App Engine. I made some changes to the LocalSettings.php file to accommodate differences between localhost and Google - mainly the SQL database and  $wgServer. I tried to run the standard mw_config setup procedure, but it never completed - stopping somewhere during table creation (I think). Instead, I restored a copy of the localhost database onto the Google Cloud SQL database.

It is almost working; it can read the database, log a user in, save a change to a page...but there is a strange problem with the links between pages. Links on the page are missing the '?title=xxxx' part e.g.

/index.php/Special:UserLogin

instead of

/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin

This makes it pretty unusable.

Does anyone have any experience with running Mediawiki on Google App Engine (GAE)? I need to know what config changes or page changes I need to make to get those links working correctly.

LocalSettings.php

```
<?php
# This file was automatically generated by the MediaWiki 1.21.2
# installer. If you make manual changes, please keep track in case you
# need to recreate them later.
#
# See includes/DefaultSettings.php for all configurable settings
# and their default values, but don't forget to make changes in _this_
# file, not there.
#
# Further documentation for configuration settings may be found at:
# http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

$wgSitename = "Shattered Screens";
$wgMetaNamespace = "Shattered_Screens";

## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
#$wgServer = "http://localhost:8080";
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
  $wgServer = "http://wiki.shatteredscreens.com";
}else{
  $wgServer = "http://localhost:8080";
}

## The relative URL path to the skins directory
$wgStylePath = "$wgScriptPath/skins";

## The relative URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogo             = "$wgStylePath/common/images/wiki.png";

## UPO means: this is also a user preference option

$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = "ivan.hawkes@shatteredscreens.com";
$wgPasswordSender = "ivan.hawkes@shatteredscreens.com";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = true; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
#$wgDBserver = "localhost";
$wgDBname = "mediawiki";
$wgDBuser = "someaccount";
$wgDBpassword = "somepassword";

# Database server settings for local / GAE
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
  $wgDBserver = ":/cloudsql/shattered-screens-wiki:mediawiki";
}else{
  $wgDBserver = "localhost";
}

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBprefix = "";

# MySQL table options to use during installation or update
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

# Experimental charset support for MySQL 5.0.
$wgDBmysql5 = false;

## Shared memory settings
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
$wgMemCachedServers = array();

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = false;
#$wgUseImageMagick = true;
#$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from http://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;

## If you use ImageMagick (or any other shell command) on a
## Linux server, this will need to be set to the name of an
## available UTF-8 locale
$wgShellLocale = "en_US.utf8";

## If you want to use image uploads under safe mode,
## create the directories images/archive, images/thumb and
## images/temp, and make them all writable. Then uncomment
## this, if it's not already uncommented:
#$wgHashedUploadDirectory = false;

## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publically accessible from the web.
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./languages/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = "en-gb";

$wgSecretKey = "xxx";

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = "xxx";

## Default skin: you can change the default skin. Use the internal symbolic
## names, ie 'standard', 'nostalgia', 'cologneblue', 'monobook', 'vector':
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";

## For attaching licensing metadata to pages, and displaying an
## appropriate copyright notice / icon. GNU Free Documentation
## License and Creative Commons licenses are supported so far.
$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";

# Query string length limit for ResourceLoader. You should only set this if
# your web server has a query string length limit (then set it to that limit),
# or if you have suhosin.get.max_value_length set in php.ini (then set it to
# that value)
$wgResourceLoaderMaxQueryLength = -1;

# The following permissions were set based on your choice in the installer
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;


# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
```

app.yaml

```
application: shattered-screens-wiki
version: initialtest
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Static pages
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: mediawiki/\1
  upload: mediawiki/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true
  secure: always

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|css))$
  static_files: mediawiki/\1
  upload: mediawiki/.+\.(gif|png|jpg|css)$
  application_readable: true
  secure: always

# Misc files.
- url: /(.+\.(xsd|txt|))$
  static_files: mediawiki/\1
  upload: mediawiki/.+\.(xsd|txt)$
  application_readable: true
  secure: always

# Serve php5 scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php5)$
  script: mediawiki/\1

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: mediawiki/\1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`$wgArticlePath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgArticlePath) to set the format of internal links. Try setting it to `{$wgScript}?title=$1`

`/index.php/Special:UserLogin` is actually the default address structure for [installations on non CGI servers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aShort_URL), and would also work on [most](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgUsePathInfo) servers

Comment: This answer was very nearly right and provided enough information for me to work out the little details. Since the default setting for   $wgArticlePath works just fine on the test server I added in a line just after the one setting $wgServer for the live server   $wgArticlePath =  "{$wgScriptPath}?title=$1"; will allow the links to work correctly on your live server.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you exactly, but glad it worked out anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
- url: /.*
  script: mediawiki/index.php
```

At the end of your `app.yaml` file, it will make sure that all other requests get routed to mediawiki main script.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the settings as the following better due to having more friendly Urls for SEO.

```
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki"; // or /w/ like Wikipedia
$wgArticlePath = "$wgScriptPath/$1";
```

Actually, any form of links can be parsed by MediaWiki properly if it is specified app.yaml.

So you can either set

```
- url: /.*
  script: mediawiki/index.php
```

or

```
# Serve php5 scripts.
- url: /wiki/(.+\.php5)$
  script: wiki/\1

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /wiki/(.+\.php)$
  script: wiki/\1

# deal with the real urls
- url: (.*)/(w|W)iki/(.*)
  script: wiki/index.php
  secure: optional
```

For the first option, the downside of it is that you can't redirect broken links to a custom 404 page.

I have a complete workable MediaWiki instance running on Google App Engine here (http://mediawiki-on-gae.appspot.com/). There are other information you might find them useful too.